# Windows 8, Hyper-V, Wireless and Remote Desktop

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8, remote-desktop, hyper-v

I've got a Win8 Pro machine and I've got Hyper-V set up with a Win7 VM.  The Win8 host has a wireless NIC and I didn't have difficulty getting the VM to have internet access using an external Virtual Switch.  My problem is with getting Remote Desktop to the VM from a machine other than the Win8 host.

When I connect with RD from the host to the VM, it works fine.  But when I try to connect to the Win7 VM from a Win8 notebook, sometimes the Win7 VM "answers", but sometimes the Win8 host "answers".  In other words, even though I specify the Win7 machine's name from the notebook, RD often winds up connecting to the Win8 host machine.

Is it even possible to make this configuration work right?  If so, any ideas on how to do it?